# Why does my code reject negative user inputs when I test it manually but not through " check50 cs50/problems/2022/x/cash"?

Tags: c, cs50

This is the code that I am trying to test.

I have tried multiple times to change the type of loop that I used or to even change where I placed it (either in the "int get_cents" function or where it is now).

Could it be that because I am using a do while loop - the code doesn't initially reject the negative inputs and that is the reason why when I run check50 - I get this result:

running ./cash_test 0...
sending input -10...
checking that input was rejected...

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int get_cents(void);
int calculate_quarters(int cents);
int calculate_dimes(int cents);
int calculate_nickels(int cents);
int calculate_pennies(int cents);

int main(void)
{
    // Ask how many cents the customer is owed
    int cents;
    do
    {
    cents = get_cents();
    }
    while (cents < 1);
    {
    // Calculate the number of quarters to give the customer
    int quarters = calculate_quarters(cents);
    cents = cents - quarters * 25;

    // Calculate the number of dimes to give the customer
    int dimes = calculate_dimes(cents);
    cents = cents - dimes * 10;

    // Calculate the number of nickels to give the customer
    int nickels = calculate_nickels(cents);
    cents = cents - nickels * 5;

    // Calculate the number of pennies to give the customer
    int pennies = calculate_pennies(cents);
    cents = cents - pennies * 1;

    // Sum coins
    int coins = quarters + dimes + nickels + pennies;

    // Print total number of coins to give the customer
    printf("%i\n", coins);
    }
}

int get_cents(void)
{
    // TODO
    return get_int("how many cents? ");
}

int calculate_quarters(int cents)
{
    // TODO
     return cents/25;

}

int calculate_dimes(int cents)
{
    // TODO
    return cents/10;
}

int calculate_nickels(int cents)
{
    // TODO
    return cents/5;
}

int calculate_pennies(int cents)
{
    // TODO
    return cents/1;
}
```

Why is my code working well only when I test it manually?

Comment: Based on the insufficient code you've posted, I couldn't even try to hazard a guess. Not even sure what the issue is.

Comment: The code you posted looks incomplete

Comment: Testing for `cents < 1` also rejects zero — and the test system may not like that.

Comment: Please reasd [ask] and [mre] and take the [tour].

Comment: @aviberger
 - I was unable to insert the entire code before but I just made the edit. You should be able to get  a clear view noe

Comment: @user16217248 - please have another look. I have added all the code

Comment: I see you have added more code but you do realize that `calculate_pennies` does absolutely nothing?

Comment: @user16217248 - yes i do realize. It was already part of the probelm set and he info provided said not to chnage that part of the code.

So now I just want to understand why when i run check50 - the code doesn't ject negative inputs but it does when I do it manually

Comment: You are using a generalized get_int() function to get the input. ints can legitimately be negative. There is nothing to suggest that it does any input validation beyond retrieving only ints. This seems to match your stated experience. I don't know what the source of your expectations was, but your evidence indicates that you will have to revise them & provide such checking yourself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From the narrative of the error you get from the checker application, it appears that the requirement of the test is that the program is supposed to immediately indicate that an invalid negative value was entered and the program is supposed to end.  Instead of a "while" loop where a retry is allowed, you might try the following code snippet.

```
    // Ask how many cents the customer is owed
    int cents;

    cents = get_cents();

    if (cents < 0)
    {
        printf("A negative value was entered and rejected\n");
        return -1;
    }
```

This would result in an output as follows if a value of "-10" were entered.

```
@Una:~/C_Programs/Console/cash_test/bin/Release$ ./cash_test 
how many cents? -10
A negative value was entered and rejected
@Una:~/C_Programs/Console/cash_test/bin/Release$
```

You might give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

The `get_cents` function here will *not* reprompt if a negative number is entered because that test is in main. It is explicit in [the spec](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/1/cash/) that the reprompt should be *within* the `get_cents` function:

> Implement `get_cents` in such a way that the function prompts the user for a number of cents using `get_int` and then returns that number as an `int`. If the user inputs a negative `int`, your code should prompt the user again.